# JavaScript - Detecting External Site Protocol - Client-side

Tags: javascript, https, protocols, client-side, tracking

I want to know a protocol of a site which is not my current page

E.g. I execute code and the current page which the code is executed on is http://www.example.org, and I want to get the protocol of  which is https:
What I know is `window.location.protocol` should return the current page, which is `http:`, but **is** there something like `'google.com'.protocol`  to return `https:` ..

Thank you :)

***My code:***

```
var returnProtocolOf(site_url) = function {
    return (String(site_url)).location.protocol // VIRTUAL COMMAND
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so with `a` elements:

```
function getProtocol(url){
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    return link.protocol;
}
```

You can also just `match` it with an expression:

```
var protocol = url.match(/^([a-z]+?:)\/\//)[1];
```

Checks might be needed.

Comment: Thanks, actually worked!
But I can't understand the `match`, Nvm, I will try to look it up